# Обновлятор WebDriver

Tags: java

Приветствую всех!

Никак не могу понять, как мне качать обновы программно и где находятся драйвера?
Есть-ли, кросс-браузерное решение со всеми драйверами в одном месте?

Или нужно по отдельности делать?

ChromeDriver.exe
OperaDriver.exe

и т.д.?

Кто-то может подсказать, как делать обновы этим драйверам?Где находятся и как к ним обращаться через прогу?

Пожалуйста подскажите, как мне это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый драйвер разрабатывается под определенный браузер командой разработчиков этого же браузера. Искать их, соответственно, нужно отдельно.

Для обновления и управления зависимостями можно использовать maven, но придется пользоваться сторонними решениями. [Например](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) .
Иначе скачивать драйвера отдельно и подкладывать в проект.